# Why spring security kerberos extension 1.0.0.M2 is not working for jdk 1.6.0_22 and above

Tags: spring-security

The spring security kerberos extension 1.0.0.M2 is working for jdk1.6.0_18 and below, but failed in new jdk 1.6.0_22 and 1.6.0_23 with the following exceptions:

```
Negotiate Header was invalid: Negotiate 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
org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Kerberos validation not succesfull  at org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator.validateTicket(SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator.java:69)
 at org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider.java:86)
 at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.doAuthentication(ProviderManager.java:120)
 at org.springframework.security.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationManager.authenticate(AbstractAuthenticationManager.java:48)
 at org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.web.SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:131)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
 at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:188)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
 at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:149)
 at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
 at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:555)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:861)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:579)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1584)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: GSSException: Failure unspecified at GSS-API level (Mechanism level: Specified version of key is not available (44))  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
 at org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator.validateTicket(SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator.java:67)
 ... 25 more
Caused by: GSSException: Failure unspecified at GSS-API level (Mechanism level: Specified version of key is not available (44))  at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5Context.acceptSecContext(Krb5Context.java:741)
 at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:323)
 at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:267)
 at sun.security.jgss.spnego.SpNegoContext.GSS_acceptSecContext(SpNegoContext.java:874)
 at sun.security.jgss.spnego.SpNegoContext.acceptSecContext(SpNegoContext.java:541)
 at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:323)
 at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:267)
 at org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator$KerberosValidateAction.run(SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator.java:146)
 at org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator$KerberosValidateAction.run(SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator.java:136)
 ... 28 more
Caused by: KrbException: Specified version of key is not available (44)  at sun.security.krb5.EncryptionKey.findKey(EncryptionKey.java:527)
 at sun.security.krb5.KrbApReq.authenticate(KrbApReq.java:260)
 at sun.security.krb5.KrbApReq.<init>(KrbApReq.java:134)
 at sun.security.jgss.krb5.InitSecContextToken.<init>(InitSecContextToken.java:79)
 at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5Context.acceptSecContext(Krb5Context.java:724)
 ... 36 more
SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Comment: The error message that you are getting:

KrbException: Specified version of key is not available (44) at sun.security.krb5.EncryptionKey.findKey(EncryptionKey.java:527) 

Indicates that one of two things is happening:

1. The KVNO of the keytab you are using does not match what is specified in the ticket
2. The keytab is not valid to decrypt the ticket

The 1st might occur if someone messed with your AD, the 2nd can occur if your keytab has somehow become corrupt.

Comment: If this is a development environment then you can post your keytab and I'll see about decrypting your token and give you a better answer.

If this is a production machine then posting your keytab is a huge security risk and you should not do it!

I'll try out this combination to see if I can reproduce the problem in my lab.

Grant

Comment: Thanks Grant! I will try to attach my keytab file later. But this keytab file works with the jdk 1.6.0_18, but not jdk1.6.0_22/23. Why is that? Thanks again.

Comment: Your header seems to be ok.  I got to the point where I needed the encryption keys and got the following information out of the key: (pvno = 5, WAM.WESTERNASSET.LOCAL, HTTP/devwarch1.wam.westernasset.local) so it appears that there is nothing wrong with the header data.  I suspect that something has changed in the guts of sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5Context.acceptSecContext or that something has changed in your AD.  Have you verified that it works simultaneously?  Do you have both JDK's installed on the machine and simply switching $JAVA_HOME causes this error?

Comment: Thanks again Grant! I have multiple JDK's installed on my box (1.6.0_18, 1.6.0_22 and 1.6.0_23).  By switching the $JAVA_HOME inside the tomcat, I found that it works for u18 not u22 and u23.  I can see the problem.  From header the pvno is 5, but when I using jdk ktab to list my ktab file, I got the following:  D:\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\bin>ktab -l -k devwarch1_http.keytab
Keytab name: D:\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\bin\devwarch1_http.keytab
KVNO    Principal
----------------------------------------------
  13     HTTP/devwarch1@WAM.WESTERNASSET.LOCAL

The kvno is 13.  Why there is difference?

Comment: I definitely think we're on the right track here but I'm not sure why the KVNO would change with the version of the JDK.  I'll do a bit more digging.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is resolved by setting the kvno to be zero in the keytab file.

Comment: use the ktpass command to specify the kvno version -- see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324144

Answer (score 2):

So the problem seemed to be that the kvno did not match (it was 5 with v1.6.18 but 13 in v1.6.22).

If you generated the keytab with a mechanism that allows you to set the kvno to 0, then the kvno may be ignored (implementation dependent).  MIT Kerberos does this and it seems that the JDK also supports.

The kvno is simply used to find the key.  So, it's valuable to have the right kvno because it makes things simpler for the system.  But it is not a security risk to have it set to 0.

Grant